Time synchronization between Ubuntu (America/New_York) and Windows (SGT) using w32tm
I'm trying to synchronize time between an Ubuntu server and a Windows PC (set to Singapore Time, SGT) using the Windows Time service. Here's my setup:

Ubuntu server: Running as NTP server (set to America/New_York)

Windows PC: Set to SGT


On the Windows PC, I’ve configured w32tm (w32tm \resync) to use the Ubuntu server as its time source. Here’s the command I used:
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:“10.221.24.85” /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:YES /update

After setting the time source, I restarted the Windows Time service and attempted to resync:
net stop w32time
net start w32time
w32tm /resync

What I get is that my command runs successfully but the time on both PC remain their respective time zone timing. My goal is to have the Windows PC always show the exact same time as the Ubuntu server, regardless of the time zone the Windows PC is in.
My questions:
How can I configure the Windows PC to automatically show the time zone of the Ubuntu NTP server?
If automatic time zone adjustment isn’t possible, what’s the best way to ensure the Windows PC always reflects the exact time shown on the Ubuntu server?
Thank you for your help in advance.

what’s the best way to ensure the Windows PC always reflects the exact time shown on the Ubuntu server? tell us what time is on the two hosts. Set the time on the Windows host to within a couple of minutes of the other host and see if that works.

 My goal is to have the Windows PC always show the exact same time as the Ubuntu server, which timezone do you want on the PC?

Time synchronization never uses time zones, so you should not/never use time zones in your testing and calculation. Specifically, you should query for UTC when you are inspecting the time: wmic /namespace:\\root\CIMV2\ path Win32_UTCTime GET year,month,day,hour,minute,second

@GregAskew, Thanks for your reply.  I followed your steps to set the time on my Windows PC to be half an hour apart from the Ubuntu host. After running the resync command, the time on the Windows PC matched the time on the Linux server. Thank you!

@JaromandaX, I wish to set them in SGT time zone.

well, your computer already is ... just set the appropriate timezone on the Ubuntu server. Is that the issue? You don't know how to set the timezone in Linux?

Hi @JaromandaX, after I set them to the same timezone, and then on changing the time on the windows to be a few minutes/hours apart, I was able to use the w32tm /resync and the time on windows synched to match ubuntu time. I was just curious to know if it is possible to sync the times even when they are on different timezones. But as I understand now, to run the time sync they have to be on the same timezones.

proper time synching should not care about timezone, the "server" should be sending UTC and the "client" should expect UTC -

But as I understand now, to run the time sync they have to be on the same timezones. No. Absolutely not. Time synchronization has nothing to do with time zones.

@GregAskew time synchronization does not need the same time zone, but the synchronization for the server and client will be using the UTC? And the time zone changes are then applied by the OS, is my understanding correct?

Time synchronization only uses UTC and never used time zones. Everything about time zones should be removed from the question.

NTP has no concept of time zones. It distributes time in UTC.
The time zone config is furthermore not global on even a single computer. Each process can define it's own time zone, and different users can have different settings.
As an quick example:
[~]$ TZ=UTC date; TZ=Europe/Oslo date; TZ=Asia/Singapore date
Thu Aug 15 14:18:52 UTC 2024
Thu Aug 15 16:18:52 CEST 2024
Thu Aug 15 22:18:52 +08 2024

In less than  10ms three commands was spawned with different time zones. By the same user. On the same computer.

I think I have better understanding of NTP nw. Thank you
But there is one more issue I am unable to fix. So there is another windows PC which I connect to the same Ubuntu server (using PCIe Ethernet card slot) and they are on a different network .  Now when I use the same commands : w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:“192.168.0.100” /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:YES /update and then the same net stop w32time, net start w32time, w32tm /resync, I get the output that the computer did not resync because no time data was available. Any idea what might be the issue? The /source shows LOCL.

Please don't ask new questions in the comments.

Noted. I have asked a separate question.
